# Jquery function implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I write this function for getting xpath location:

JQuery (this function get xpath):

```
function getXPath(node, path) {
        path = path || [];
        if(node.parentNode) {
          path = getXPath(node.parentNode, path);
        }

        if(node.previousSibling) {
          var count = 1;
          var sibling = node.previousSibling
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {count++;}
            sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
          } while(sibling);
          if(count == 1) {count = null;}
        } else if(node.nextSibling) {
          var sibling = node.nextSibling;
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {
              var count = 1;
              sibling = null;
            } else {
              var count = null;
              sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
            }
          } while(sibling);
        }

        if(node.nodeType == 1) {
          path.push(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() + (node.id ? "[@id='"+node.id+"']" : count > 0 ? "["+count+"]" : ''));
        }
        return path;
      };
```

and I have an iframe:

```
<iframe id="frameID" width="100%" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

But Now I have a problem how to integrate my jquery function and where to when i click somewhere in Iframe get xpath result?

Comment: For what do you need jQuery? Did you wrote the xpath-function on your own?

Comment: I need for get results when I click...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote that function? -- That code was written nearly 5 years ago on DZone: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4349 -- This includes instructions for usage for the function.

Comment: Yes, you all right, I'm not really good in english, sorry aboiut that

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that when the iframe location is in the same domain as the page embedding it.

If so, get the Document from the iframe (`document.getElementById('frameId').contentDocument`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe#p-contentDocument)) and add a click event listener to it. The event you're receiving will contain a reference to the target node.

Comment: There are a few ways to communicate between documents, but for that you must have control over both. Look for "same origin policy" (e.g. at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) and related, like window.postMessage.